# How to read all csv files that begin with consonant?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

```
import os
for file in os.listdir("/content/drive/MyDrive/BigData2021/Lecture23/datasets"):
    if file.endswith(".csv"):
        print(os.path.join(file))

cities.csv
airports.csv
data_scientist_salaries.csv
```

I want to read this CSV file with spark which begins consonant without tell CSV filename. How to do that?

Answer (score 2):

Using wildcard `[b-df-hj-np-tv-z]*.csv` in the path should do the job:

```
df = spark.read.csv("/your_directory/datasets/[b-df-hj-np-tv-z]*.csv")
```

Comment: [a-z]*.csv is that mean consonant letters? or just sort by ascending?

Comment: I need to read only csv file which begins consonant.

Comment: Ur example only read data_scientist_salaries.csv also need to read cities.csv cause it begin with consonant as well.

Comment: @sasaii sorry I misunderstood your question, I thought you wanted files which start with lowercase. I updated the wildcard regex, now it should only load `cities.csv` and `data_scientist_salaries.csv` but not `airports.csv`.